# Corda postgres table setup during the deployNodes

Tags: corda

I'm trying to build nodes which needs to be deployed in Multiple VM's.
When I run the deployNodes, the corresponding tables are getting created.

Is there anyway that after copying the nodejs to VM and execute commands to generate the tables on the Postgres in the corresponding VM machines.

Answer (score 1):

- First, you need to create one schema per node inside your database. For instance, [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/3.3/node-database.html#postgresql) you can find the steps for PostgreSQL database.
- Then, set `initializeSchema` to `true` inside the `node.conf` of your node; with this option enabled, the node will automatically create all its tables when it starts for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

1. DeployNodes is a Gradle plugin which will help you to set up the node configurations. Database tables are created only when you run the node.
   You connect to the default in-memory H2 database or you connect to Postgres, the logic to generate the tables in the database is the same. By default, all the required tables are generated automatically by the node in the database.